# problema ao renomear um projeto no eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]antes de formatar meu computador, eu renomeiava um projeto no eclipse e a pasta no workspace mudava de nome no momento que renomeiava junto ao projeto, agora eu renomeio o projeto muda de nome só o projeto mas a pasta continua o mesmo nome e aparece o nome da pasta ao lado do nome do projeto, porfavor alguem me ajudar a achar esta configuração para mudar os 2 juntos novamente preciso muito, ja excluir a ide e baixei denovo e não resolveu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao criar o projeto confirme se você está deixando a opção "Use Default Location" marcada. Aparentemente pelo que eu testei, quando você desmarca essa opção mesmo que coloque o projeto dentro pasta workspace, quando você renomear o projeto, o nome da pasta dentro do workspace não será alterado. Consigo imaginar duas opções:

1. Tente criar o projeto marcando a opção "Use Default Location".
2. Se não funcionar, vá direto na pasta onde o projeto se encontra e mude o nome manualmente.

Comment: entendir, acho que a melhor opção foi copiar e colar o projeto com o nome que quero e apagar o antigo de dois nomes